# Java ScheduledExecutorService ScheduleWithFixedDelay adding unexpected delay after some iterations?

Tags: java, scheduledexecutorservice

I ran scheduling program on 2 m/c both windows but different configuration-

```
public class testScheduling {
    static boolean header = false;
    static ScheduledExecutorService m_scheduleService;
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        WorkerThread worker = new WorkerThread();
        m_scheduleService = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);

        m_scheduleService.scheduleWithFixedDelay(worker, 1, 1,  TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

    }



     static public class WorkerThread implements Runnable{

            public WorkerThread(){
            }

            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    processCommand();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    System.out.println("something wrong in thread");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            private void processCommand() throws InterruptedException {
                Date d = new Date();
                System.out.println("print ...." + Utility.getDateToString(d));

            }

        }
}
```

On 1 m/c the results was -

```
print ....2016-01-28 15:42:45.289
print ....2016-01-28 15:42:45.289
print ....2016-01-28 15:42:45.289
print ....2016-01-28 15:42:45.289
print ....2016-01-28 15:42:45.289
print ....2016-01-28 15:42:45.289
print ....2016-01-28 15:42:45.289
print ....2016-01-28 15:42:45.299
print ....2016-01-28 15:42:45.299
print ....2016-01-28 15:42:45.299
print ....2016-01-28 15:42:45.299
print ....2016-01-28 15:42:45.299
```

----after some interval 10 ms of difference.

On another m/c, result was

```
print ....2016-01-28 05:06:54.239
print ....2016-01-28 05:06:54.239
print ....2016-01-28 05:06:54.239
print ....2016-01-28 05:06:54.239
print ....2016-01-28 05:06:54.239
print ....2016-01-28 05:06:54.239
print ....2016-01-28 05:06:54.255
print ....2016-01-28 05:06:54.255
print ....2016-01-28 05:06:54.255
print ....2016-01-28 05:06:54.255
print ....2016-01-28 05:06:54.255
print ....2016-01-28 05:06:54.255
```

--Second m/c after some iteration shows difference 16 ms.

Why is there this difference for 2 different m/c? 
Why is there a long delay after some iteration? 
Can this unexpected delay be removed?

Comment: Is both windows machine runs on synchronized time?

Comment: One m/c is in indian time and second m/c is NY time on amazon. Both m/c synchronized to internet time.  I was speaking of results in relative terms. Why is there 10 or 16 ms delay after some iterations. and this 10 or 16 ms delay is related to m/c configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot expect the Scheduler(in one or more machines) to run exactly at the same time every time.

I have quoted the below caution from java docs of  `ScheduledExecutorService`

```
Beware however that expiration of a relative delay need not coincide with the current Date at 
which the task is enabled due to network time synchronization protocols, clock drift, 
or other factors.
```

[Reference java doc link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html)

[NTP](http://www.ntp.org/) should be able to help you understand the reason.

Comment: Does NTP also account for gap of 16 ms(or 10 ms) after some iterations of running? Why is there a gap at all?

Comment: According to the JavaDocs it seems likely to be the reason.

Comment: If you are satisfied with the answer, do mark it. It may be helpful for someone with same issue

Comment: Your answer explains the problem but no solution? Is there a way to achieve to avoid this gap? And run scheduling at 1 ms interval?

Comment: Yes out of 2 out of 3 questions I have answered. To answer the last one, could you give me some more information on what your trying to accomplish?

Comment: Thanks for help Adheep. I needs to schedule a recurring a call to a function with precision of 1-3 ms.